# R - adding values to a matrix, which loop to use and memory usage

Tags: r, loops, matrix, memory, ram

I'm developing an R package and for some processes within it, I need to calculate a bunch of large matrices. However a lot of ram was used so I tried doing some investigation.

(I tried following the general known advice of avoiding for loops where possible and using apply's family instead)

Here's my minimal example;

```
library(pryr)

test1 <- function(nbyn) {

values <- matrix(nrow=nbyn, ncol=nbyn)
rownames(values) <- 1:nrow(values)
values[,] <- 2
lapply(rownames(values) , function(row) {
  values[row,] <<- rnorm(1)*values[row,]
})
gc()
1
}

test2 <- function(nbyn) {
  values <- matrix(nrow=nbyn, ncol=nbyn)
  rownames(values) <- 1:nrow(values)
  values[,] <- 2
  for (row in rownames(values)) {
    values[row,] <- rnorm(1)*values[row,]
  }
  gc()
  1
}

# comment at for loops indicate before/after ram that's being used in system. (manually measured)
# apply seems to have more memory leaks/left over garbage?

# run both blocks seperately in new r sessions (to clear memory)

# add startmem and stopmem into global environment as to not disturb measurement
startmem <- mem_used()
stopmem <- mem_used()
# start actual test
start <- Sys.time()
startmem <- mem_used()
for (i in 1:10) {
  test1(10000) # 2.06 -> 4.21 gb (3.50 gb after garbage collection) ---> at least 1.44gb gets left in ram?
}
gc()
stopmem <- mem_used()
print(paste0("process left ", stopmem-startmem, " bytes of ram"))
print(Sys.time()-start)

#---

# add startmem and stopmem into global environment as to not disturb measurement
startmem <- mem_used()
stopmem <- mem_used()
# start actual test
start <- Sys.time()
startmem <- mem_used()
for (i in 1:10) {
  test2(10000) # 2.06 -> 3.87 gb (3.12 gb after garbage collection) ---> at least 1.06gb gets left in ram?
}
gc()
stopmem <- mem_used()
print(paste0("process left ", stopmem-startmem, " bytes of ram"))
print(Sys.time()-start)
```

It seems like apply is using/leaving more memory which the garbage collector does not take care of. I think it has to do with it trying to combine results, but I'm not so sure. For instance, could it have to do with the `<<-` assignment? Is apply generally speaking more of a memory hog than regular for loops? It seems problematic that I don't want to save the apply values but can't ignore them.

I know it's kind of ugly to use the `<<-` assignment, but it's the only way to put something in an outside reference from an apply and I need to use names for indexing, making it difficult not to do this.

This specific example works with the names of the matrix instead of indices because my package works the same way for readability/ease of implementation.

And the last question; why does R report it has so little memory in use, while in reality it leaves a lot of unused data in memory causing problems?...

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Edit1; I will use regular for loops in this use case.

Comment: Your `lapply` example is (i) bad practice and (ii) probably prevents the JIT compiler from doing its work. Use the `for` loop (or preferably avoid any loop and use vectorized subassignment).

Comment: @Roland Can you elaborate on these points? I'm kind of curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: If you do heavy computations where you have to use for loops, I would recoment to write these parts in c++ and than use Rcpp to integrate that code into your package.

Comment: @HolgerBarlt That might work in this specific example, the problem is however that my package is dependent on a lot of computation by other packages. So I can't do much in regards to that.